# How to terminate SQL script before creating procedure or function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following script in SQL Server 2014 for creating a scalar function named `GetFiscalPeriod`. The script must **check for the existence of the function by its name before creating it**.

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where 
     id = object_id(N'[dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod]') 
     and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsScalarFunction') = 1)
--want to terminate the whole batch
RETURN --doesn't work the way I want
--seems to terminate IF batch only
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod] ()
Returns INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (select MAX(Id) from dbo.__FiscalPeriod__);
END
```

I want it to terminate the whole thing as it reaches inside IF body. (`RETURN`)

The problem is no matter how I change the code, either it jumps to `CREATE FUNCTION` giving this error:

> There is already an object named 'GetFiscalPeriod' in the database.

Or giving this syntax error (when I try to put `CREATE FUNCTION` in the IF clause):

> 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Question is:

Is there anyway to tell SQL to ignore the rest of the script when the object name exists?

### Note:

I used to drop the function beforehand, and it works. But I don't want to drop and recreate everything every time.

```
...
IF EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where 
     id = object_id(N'[dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod]') 
     and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsScalarFunction') = 1)
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod] --works
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod] ()
...
```

Comment: Make the create statement dynamic SQL, and execute using `sp_executesql`

Comment: This script is not a single batch but multiple batches (separated by `GO` separators).

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks I edited the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for existence, if existed ALTER else CREATE:
you must exec query as string.

```
IF not EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsScalarFunction') = 1)
execute sp_executesql N'
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod] () 
Returns INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (select MAX(Id) from dbo.__FiscalPeriod__);
END'
else
N'
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod] () 
Returns INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (select MAX(Id) from dbo.__FiscalPeriod__);
END'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that check in the following way using dynamic sql.

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) 
  ='CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFiscalPeriod] ()
  Returns INT
  AS
  BEGIN
  RETURN (select MAX(Id) from dbo.__FiscalPeriod__);
  END' 
IF Not EXISTS (funname) --function name for which the existence should be 
begin                   --checked
exec sp_executesql @var            
end
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Without dynamic SQL, you'll need to raise an error to stop the calling application from running the remainder of the script. This can be done with the `-b` command-line argument in the case of `SQLCMD`:

```
SQLCMD -S YourServer -d YourDatabase -E -iYourScript.sql -I -b
```

The T-SQL within the executed script to raise the error and terminate execution:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.GetFiscalPeriod', 'FN') IS NOT NULL
    RAISERROR('Function GetFiscalPeriod already exists', 16, 1);
```

If you are using SQL Server 2016 SP1 or later, you can use `CREATE OR ALTER` to avoid dropping the object beforehand. It seems to me you would want to recreate the function even if it exists since it may be different.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS

Create the function first with this key phrase

Comment: thanks for answering but this doesn't seem to be sql server syntax